# Blank page after searching for keywords for products magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to search for products using keywords for the products to be rendered in frontend using my custom plugin.
After i search for the keyword, i get a log for the products searched but it shows blank page,without any debug or exception logs.

How to i find out the errors or which module ?

Comment: Have you checked Magento's own logs, and apcache / PHP's error logs?

Comment: my system.log says: main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

Comment: any update on the same ?